# How to get the precise time of the consumption function by using SYSTICK timer?

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

As far as I knew, SYSTICK Timer is a 24-bit down counter. For now, I need to know the precise consumption time for the memcpy function. Suppose I set SysTick->RELOAD = 511, it will turn out two cases as the following description.

Define: 
1. One cycle means 511 to 0 must be finish.
2. Two or more cycles mean 511 to 0, 511 to 0, ... , 511 to 0, 511 to i, i in [0, 511].

Case 1: Offset is small or normal, so the memcpy will finish in one cycles.

Case 2: Offset is very big, e.g. 16K. So the memcpy will finish in two or more cycles.

How do I get the "cycles" ?

Comment: Either use bigger reload or enable interrupt and increment other variable in it (won't be that precise, but with high-enough reload, you won't notice the difference ...or you can estimate by the new over-counter)

Answer (score 1):

### [See the documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s08.html)

SysTick has 24bit counter, RELOAD@0xE000E014 and CURRENT@0xE000E018. There is nothing easier than `RELOAD=0x00FFFFFF; call_the_func(); unsigned diff = RELOAD-CURRENT`.

Enable interrupts and configure `SysTick_Handler()` to increment some other value (to get bigger range) if needed. You can then calculate `my_global*(RELOAD-few) + (RELOAD-CURRENT)`.

*I use SysTick for 10ms timers - just incrementing global counter every 10ms (from the interrupt) and observe the difference from value stored when started ;)*

Comment: It rolls over as well, beg=current, do stuff, end=current, diff=(beg-end)&0xFFFFFF, so long as you stay within a cycle (or detect the rollovers)

Comment: @dwelch: Sure, like my timers, but storing both the global counter and `SysTick->CURRENT`, then computing the diff (for whatever period, 10ms global counter rolls over after more than a year).

Comment: sure. all I meant to say was you can init the timer once and not touch it again, and just use it as much as you want by comparing the diff rather than the start - now.